# Mongoose wont push object with new key: value to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose with Next.js, I made a model for User with one "page" object, and every time there is any change inside, I just update it as:

```
xUser.page.array = * the new array *
```

and it works well, now I made a new option to add something to the array, and it works well as:

```
xUser.page.array.push({ key1: value1, key2: value2, })
```

but now i decided to create a new key, "value3" and I'm trying to push it like that:

```
xUser.page.array.push({ key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3})
```

and after that:

```
user.markModified('page')
await user.save()
```

it does save the object inside the array, but without the new key and value ("key3")
and when I console.log the memorized array (xUser.page.array) it does show the new key&value in the inserted object, but as I said not in the db as well :/
how can I add the new key&value?
thanks!

**Critical edit: looks like when i remove one key value from the object and push, for exa `{ key2: value2, key3: value3 }` (without key1/val1) it does work, so somehow its limited to just 2 key values..**

Comment: So 2 key values work and 3 don't? Have you put some max length to any field in the schema?

Comment: have u add 'key3: value3' to the target model 'user' for ur mongo db ? ,

Comment: I dont have max length or something, and yeah 2 key values work, i mean it was the "default" object build (by default i mean the regular structure that i always push).

Comment: @Adan my User model contains just the "page" and typed as object, inside i change the blocks prop without changing the parent model.

Comment: @ShiNxzz , I think you must add value3 type to that object in ur 'user' model